# How to get a Dynamic value to JSP from controller in MVC Architecture

Tags: jsp

Im New to JSP .

I have a requirement , where im developing application web page, having one controller class named controller.java 
and i have bean class named Bean.java to share the data between my jsp page A.jsp and controlle.java,

when jsp is getting loaded assume im fetching value from database via controller class and it is xxx which will be set in the bean class and im able to access the same in the jsp also.
now after jsp being loaded when an event is generated ill be calling the controller.java again to fetch the value from the database.. assume now the value is yyyyy .... but im still getting the intial value in hte jsp as xxx from the bean class.

if i refresh the jsp the updated value i.e yyyy is available at jsp.
please help me to fetch a updated value with out refreshing the jsp.

Regards
Govardan

Answer (score 0):

The jsp page is on the client side, so to update it with new info the page will need to talk to the server again (that is why the value updates when you refresh the jsp). You can use AJAX  update the client-side page without making a new page request:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info

Comment: hi Thanks for the reply , but here in this ajax code we get the result in the form of xml and im getting the whole jsp.page in html format in the result , but the criteria is like i have java code to execute the db and it gives me some result i shuld be able to get that as value instead....